# How can you synchronize daily emails when using Amazon Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask

I have a Flask application that is running on an EC2 instance, set up to send emails using Flask-Mail with Gmail. The application is configured to send emails on certain events, some go instantly when an action happens, others are daily summary emails that are sent at a fixed time of day.
For the production environment I'm thinking of setting up a Load Balancer and switching from Gmail to Amazon SES.

I see how I will bump into an issue where I have multiple servers running due to the Load Balancer and each server would want to send their daily emails.

Is there any way to handle sending the daily emails using only one of the servers?

**[edit]**: Edited the question to be more focused on the task itself, rather than the architecture required.

Comment: Your problem encompases the entire complexity of distributed computing. Answering the question is far too complex and nuanced for a single SO answer.

Comment: With all due respect I would suggest that in AWS, many questions and solutions require a broad set of services to implement properly. The AWS service ecosystem itself is complex. This particular question does not seem unreasonable in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume each instance should be able to send emails at any time, for application event logs. So each would just connect to SES for that.

For time scheduling daily summary emails, you will want to consider using an external scheduler to call a URL endpoint in your app that will send the desired message on request. This request will only hit a single server, so it will only be sent once. See https://cron-job.org/en/ for this type of service.

Using this approach, you can can manage both event and scheduled email.

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea. It will work for the moment, thank you.

Comment: I've used it for years. Works great. You can also block by IP so only the cron service can activate the url. Keeps bots for landing on the url and sending email.

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine IMHO. I think you edited it after the first close vote. I voted to reopen. Edit it for focus and clarity and mention in the question the nature of the edit.